# how to get the MessageId value from That json response using php

Tags: php, json

{"ServiceClass":{"MessageId":"1633236883931745","Status":"0","StatusText":"success","ErrorCode":"0","ErrorText":{},"SMSCount":"1","CurrentCredit":"49.24"}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use first Json decode

```
$json_response ='{"ServiceClass":{"MessageId":"1633236883931745","Status":"0","StatusText":"success","ErrorCode":"0","ErrorText":{},"SMSCount":"1","CurrentCredit":"49.24"}}';

$array = json_decode($json_response, true);

function extractProperty($arr, $propName){
    return $arr['ServiceClass'][$propName];
}

echo 'MessageId : '.extractProperty($array, 'MessageId'). "<br>";
echo 'CurrentCredit : '.extractProperty($array, 'CurrentCredit');
```